# Long Press Gesture WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, gesture

I'm trying to add a long press gesture recognizer to my Apple Watch app. Reading the Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wklongpressgesturerecognizer) is not clear to me whether there's a delegate I should implement or what else is triggered by the long press gesture itself. Could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Long Press Gesture Recognizer has to be dragged into a Storyboard from the Object library. From there, you Control-drag it to code to set an action connection, and handle long presses within that method.